# Image showing on emulator, 7 inch tablets but not on 10 inch Android tablet (Asus Transformer)

Tags: android, image, android-layout, user-interface, layout

The app is functioning properly on 7" tablets, 10" emulators and samsung 10 inch devices.
The other images places in sw720dp get displayed in 10inch tablet except one big image (2048 X 1200).
The image is static means is in app and not downloaded via web services.

The codes are

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_repet_"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include layout="@layout/header" />

    <ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/dashboard_background"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and issue is with

```
<ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/dashboard_background"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

but header image get display.

Comment: Could it be a memory issue? (2048x1200 is quite large). Are you loading a lot of other large images as well? Are you allocating other large chunks of memory? Does the image show if you change scaleType to something else (or remove the attribute)? Do you need to set background to @null?

Comment: I changed the size of image 1/2, 1/4, 80% increased and may thing but no luck.  (Testing in process on device removing android:background="@null" and   android:scaleType="fitXY". will update you on this. Thank You

Comment: Thanks to sandeep for editing